# Getting the width in jQuery isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here but the following code for some reason is throwing up undefined variables.

What variable should I be using to get and test the width of the window?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function dostuff(){
        if (window.width < 1050) {
            console.log("not working?")
        } else {
            console.log(window.width)
        }
    }
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
            dostuff();
        });
});
```

Comment: https://www.google.de/search?q=javascript+window+width&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gFdYWOfqI8io8wfnm7LoCA

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already, you can use `$(window).width();`...

Comment: documentation [**`.width()`**](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `window` doesn't have a `width` property. You need to use:

```
window.innerWidth
```

Also, the code can be reduced by:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function dostuff() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1050) {
      console.log("not working?")
    } else {
      console.log($(window).width())
    }
  }
  $(window).resize(dostuff);
});
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus What if the outside uses Prototype or Scriptaculous or whatever? Did you understand my point of sending `$` as a parameter?